# Matcap Globe won't render properly

Tags: rendering, matcaps

I've modeled a robot arm, and the materials applied are matcaps. That model renders fine in viewport and F12. But I've also created a globe, with a matcap and a normal map. It renders properly in the viewport, but not on render.

Any advice?

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Yes, under Render Settings > FIlm check the Transparent checkbox

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise - Thanks! That did it for rendering transparency.